# Gnuplot: trailing white space

Tags: gnuplot

I've got a multiplot like this:

[image: Plot sample]

How do I remove the trailing white space added by the `xtics` interval? Relevant configurations include:

```
set xtics 10
set mxtics 5
```

Data for the `xaxis` goes up to somewhere between 135 and 140.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set your xrange explicitly if the data do not end at some nice round value.  One way to do this is to use the `stats` command (gnuplot 4.6.0) and up:

```
stats 'data.dat'
set xrange[STATS_min_x:STATS_max_x]
```

Otherwise you can `set xrange` manually (if you know the value), or use the old-fashioned method:

```
set output '/dev/null'
plot 'data.dat'
set xrange[GPVAL_DATA_X_MIN:GPVAL_DATA_X_MAX]
set output'actual_output.png'
replot
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks :) Just one detail: `stats_min_x` and `stats_max_x` must be `STATS_min_x` and `STATS_max_x`, respectively.

Comment: Let's suppose that the maximum value of one column is 4086. This can be find using STATS_max. Now, how can we round up this value to the nearest hundred 4100? Is this possible in gnuplot? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is possible, and I see you asked it as another question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17829160/how-to-control-xtics-in-gnuplot).  Thanks for the typo correction; I always get the capitalization wrong when I am too lazy to open up gnuplot and see what the variable names are.

Answer (score 2):

To disable the automatic extension of the autoscaled x-axis to the next tic mark use

```
set autoscale xfix
```

The general syntax is

```
set autoscale {<axes>{|min|max|fixmin|fixmax|fix} | fix | keepfix}
```